# react-select typescript not working properly when I substitute Select with a Component that returns Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select, react-typescript

So instead of using Select directly I thought it would be better to create a component named CustomSelect which will return Select with some properties prefilled.

The issue is that now when I use the CustomSelect component with property `isMulti={false}`
typescript does not automatically understands that `OnChange` property should be of type

```
(newValue: SingleValue<IOption>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<IOption>) => void
```

instead of

```
(newValue: SingleValue<IOption> | MultiValue<IOption>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<IOption>) => void
```

Why is this happening and is there any good workaround?

CustomSelect.tsx

```
import Select, {
  components,
  OptionProps,
  ValueContainerProps,
  Props as SelectProps,
} from "react-select";
import { IOption } from "../../Table/Types";
import "./CustomSelect.scss";

//type IOption = {
//  value: any;
//  label: string;
//  icon?: string;
//};

const { Option: OptionCointainer, ValueContainer } = components;

function OptionWithIcon(props: OptionProps<IOption>) {
  const {
    label,
    data: { icon },
  } = props;
  return (
    <OptionCointainer {...props} className="selectOption">
      {!!icon && <img src={icon} alt={label} />}
      {label}
    </OptionCointainer>
  );
}

// react-select is buggy when you try to override rendered value component
// children is being used as a workaround
function ValueWithIcon(props: ValueContainerProps<IOption>) {
  const { getValue, children } = props;
  const { label, icon } = getValue()[0];
  return (
    <ValueContainer {...props} className="selectValue">
      <>
        {!!icon && <img src={icon} alt={label} />}
        {label}
        <span className="hiddenAbsolute">{children}</span>
      </>
    </ValueContainer>
  );
}

function CustomSelect(props: SelectProps<IOption>) {
  const { options } = props;
  return (
    <Select
      isDisabled={options ? options.length < 2 : true}
      components={{
        Option: OptionWithIcon,
        ValueContainer: ValueWithIcon,
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

export default CustomSelect;
```

Filters.tsx

```
      <Select
        id="currencyFrom"
        isMulti={false}
        value={state.fromCurrency}
        // if I hover on change type is (newValue: SingleValue<IOption>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<IOption>) => void
        onChange={onValueChange("fromCurrency")}
        options={someOptions}
        isSearchable={false}
      />
      <CustomSelect
        id="currencyTo"
        isMulti={false}
        value={state.toCurrency}
        // if I hover on change type is (newValue: SingleValue<IOption> | MultiValue<IOption>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<IOption>) => void
        onChange={onValueChange("toCurrency")}
        options={someOptions}
        isSearchable={false}
      />
```

[image: Edit React Typescript (forked)]

Answer (score 4):

The `SelectProps` type you are trying to adapt is a generic type with 3 type arguments (defined [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/4b8468636bcfadf0cfe45f9a7a6c1db5dca08d9a/packages/react-select/src/useStateManager.ts#L33)). Because you provide a type for the first argument, inference is disabled the other 2 arguments and Typescript sets them to their default values instead.

If you need inference to work, you cannot provide partial type arguments, I can see 2 solutions:

- Get rid of the `Option` argument in `SelectProps<Option>` and let the `Option` type be inferred as well

```
function CustomSelect(props: SelectProps) {
```

- If you need to enforce a specific `Option` type, create another generic type for your props that only takes the 2 last arguments and let typescript infer these:

```
type CustomSelectProps<
    IsMulti extends boolean = boolean,
    Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>
> = SelectProps<Option, IsMulti, Group>;

…

function CustomSelect(props: CustomSelectProps) {
```

---

Also, because you want this type of inference to happen when using the component, you should also make your component generic, applying the same logic to the `StateManagedSelect` component type (defined [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/4b8468636bcfadf0cfe45f9a7a6c1db5dca08d9a/packages/react-select/src/stateManager.tsx#L15)).

This gives us the following component type definition, using the `CustomSelectProps`:

```
function CustomSelect<
    IsMulti extends boolean = false,
    Group extends GroupBase<IOption> = GroupBase<IOption>
>(props: SelectProps<IOption, IsMulti, Group>) {
```

[Updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-q3z9mv?file=/src/CustomSelect.tsx): you'll see I had to apply the same logic to your other components as well, as all the types depend on each other.

Comment: yeahWhat Thank you a lot for the explanation but if i use the CustomSelectProps it still does not seem to work for some reason (i've added a sandbox if it helps)

Comment: @profchaos Indeed, the component types were incomplete. I've updated the answer!